# Compass/Sass, Blueprint with ASP.NET/MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sass, compass-sass, blueprint-css

I would like to use Compass/Sass with Blueprint or 960 with ASP.NET MVC.

I am aware of Paul Bett's wonderful NuGet Package SassAndCoffee

http://blog.paulbetts.org/index.php/2011/06/06/new-release-sassandcoffee-0-9-now-not-glacially-slow/

But how can I use Compass with Blueprint or 960 as well with ASP.NET MVC?

I am also aware of these instructions:

Using Sass via Compass in ASP.NET MVC
http://paceyourself.net/2010/08/23/using-sass-via-compass-in-aspnet-mvc/

So by combining these two recommendations I should be able to use Compass/Sass with Blueprint or 960?

Also is there a good book or tutorials now available for Compass/Sass?
I see that there will be the book by Manning, "Sass and Compass in Action" but it is not ready yet.

It does seem like Compass/Sass, Blueprint,  CoffeeScript is the way to go.  I just wish there was an easy way to use these packages with ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 3):

SassAndCoffee isn't ready for Compass yet, Compass actually patches the Sass compiler to do extra stuff. It's the next big feature that SassAndCoffee will support though!

Comment: Is this still true? When should we expect this feature be released?